# Separate Domains or Subdomains for each Product?

Tags: seo

I currently develop a number of products. From an SEO standpoint, is it better to set up each product as a subdomain from my primary domain or set up entirely separate domains?

My goals are the following:

- Reach the largest number of people
- Reduce duplicated SEO efforts

My initial thought was that creating a subdomain for each product would reduce my SEO efforts to mainly focusing on my primary domain. Please tell me if my logic is incorrect.

Comment: Are the products related to each other? Do they belong to same niche?

Answer (score -2):

Do not do this.

You should own domains that are part of your brand identity: brand/business name(s), trademarks, and possibly products, but for reasons not necessarily related to SEO.

Comment: Do not do what?

Comment: "My initial thought was that creating a subdomain for each product would reduce my SEO efforts to mainly focusing on my primary domain. Please tell me if my logic is incorrect."